# Airflow: Simple DAG with one task never finishes

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have made a very simple DAG that looks like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

cleanup_command = "/home/ubuntu/airflow/dags/scripts/log_cleanup/log_cleanup.sh "

dag = DAG(
'log_cleanup',
description='DAG for deleting old logs',
schedule_interval='10 13 * * *',
start_date=datetime(2018, 3, 30),
catchup=False,
)

t1 = BashOperator(task_id='cleanup_task', bash_command=cleanup_command, dag=dag)
```

The task finishes successfully but despite of this the DAG remains in "running" status. Any idea what could cause this. The screenshot below show the issue with the DAG remaining running. The earlier runs are only finished because I manually mark status as success. [Edit: I had originally written: "The earlier runs are only finished because I manually set status to running."]

[image: Screenshot showing that status of task is finished but DAG is still running]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The earlier runs are only finished because I manually set status to running.

Are you sure your scheduler is running? You can start it with `$ airflow scheduler`, and check the [scheduler CLI command docs](https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#scheduler)  You shouldn't have to manually set tasks to running.

Your code here seems fine.  One thing you might try is restarting your scheduler.

In the Airflow metadata database, DAG run end state is disconnected from task run end state.  I've seen this happen before, but usually it resolves itself on the scheduler's next loop when it realizes all of the tasks in the DAG run have reached a final state (success, failed, or skipped).

Are you running the LocalExecutor, SequentialExecutor, or something else here?

Comment: I made a major typo. I meant to say that I manually set status to success. Otherwise it never stops. I'm sure the scheduler is running as many other DAGS work just fine. I'm using LocalExecutor.

Comment: Hmm that is weird.  Did you manually set the task state to success or the DAG run state to success?  If you swap the `bash_command` for something trivial like `uptime` do you get the same result?

Comment: I think I found the error. I had two DAGs with the same name. However, only one of them showed up in the GUI but I guess it somehow messed up the status. Thanks for all your help.