# <Apache Airflow> DAGRun doesn't stop when the job is finished

Tags: airflow

I use Airflow 1.10.9 with the **executor** of **LocalExecutor**. I have tasks that take 1 hour to complete. But after the task completed. DAGRun doesn't stop. I can only terminate it manually.

[dagrun](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMqC9.png)
[task_instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3ejz.png)

Someone had the same problem  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49612150/airflow-simple-dag-with-one-task-never-finishes)

Comment: How was this DAG triggered?

Comment: Would be helpful to share the result of `select * from dag_run where dag_id=<your_dag_id> and execution_date="<your_dag_execution_date>"`

Comment: The result of statement: `# id, dag_id, execution_date, state, run_id, external_trigger, conf, end_date, start_date
10980, Syn_nh, 2021-05-04 00:25:00.000000, success, scheduled__2021-05-03T17:25:00+00:00, 0, , 2021-05-05 02:59:35.605660, 2021-05-05 00:25:06.759904
` and `# id, dag_id, execution_date, state, run_id, external_trigger, conf, end_date, start_date
10762, Syn_nh, 2021-05-04 00:28:15.978368, success, manual__2021-05-03T17:28:15.978368+00:00, 1, ..., 2021-05-05 00:28:26.415410, 2021-05-04 00:28:16.384285
`

Comment: Okay, these are the entries from dag_run, yes, but can you send the entry for a dagrun which is not stopping (in running state). Add it to your question for better readability. Also, add the task instance entries for the same run with query `select * from task_instance where dag_id=<your_dag_id> and execution_date="<your_dag_execution_date>"` where execution date is the execution date of the dag instance which is causing a problem

Comment: @Tameem okay. I have added it!!!

Comment: @Tameem I tried running the python scripting on a jupyter notebook and it finished as expected. Not with airflow. :(